# Adding an if statement before a while loop gives wrong results

Tags: java, regex

Why does adding an `if` statement before the `while` loop result in the first match being removed?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class testRegex {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9]+");
        Matcher m = p.matcher("Name, 245 Street, City, Country, 101010");
        
        System.out.println(m.find());
        
        if(m.find()) {
            while(m.find()) {
                System.out.println(m.group());
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Nothing found");
        }
     }
}
```

The output without the `if` is correct.

```
Name
245
Street
City
Country
101010
```

Adding the `if` or anything before the `while` loop for that matter results in this:

```
245
Street
City
Country
101010
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I correct this? I'm doing this on Eclipse IDE.

Comment: *how can I correct this?* - remove the `if`

Comment: Based on documentation, ```find()``` "attempts to find **the next** subsequence of the input sequence that matches the pattern", so when you have ```println``` or ```if``` before ```while```, they "consume" one or several ```find()``` iterations.

Comment: Ok. I need the if find to print something like "Nothing found" if nothing matched.

Comment: Very strange reason to close this question. How is this `not reproducible or was caused by typos`?

Answer (score 4):

Here is an alternative approach using Java 8 streams:

```
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9]+");
Matcher m = p.matcher("Name, 245 Street, City, Country, 101010");
    
List<String> res = m.results().map(MatchResult::group)
                  .collect(Collectors.toList());
if (res.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println("Nothing found");
} else {
    System.out.println(res);
}
```

**Output:**

```
[Name, 245, Street, City, Country, 101010]
```

Answer (score 2):

`m.find()` changes state, goes to the next match if present.

```
    //NO: System.out.println(m.find());
   
    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println("Found:");
        do {
            System.out.println(m.group());
        } while (m.find());
    } else {
        System.out.println("Nothing found");
    }
```

Comment: Of course, if you want to print something, you can assign the result of `m.find()` to a variable, print it and check it in the if condition.

Comment: Added alternative `println` for when something was found. When not found there already is a `println`.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use [`matcher.reset()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#reset())?

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class testRegex {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9]+");
        Matcher m = p.matcher("Name, 245 Street, City, Country, 101010");
        
        System.out.println(m.find());
        m.reset();

        if(m.find()) {
            m.reset();
            while(m.find()) {
                System.out.println(m.group());
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Nothing found");
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Each call of "m.find" will move to the next match in within the search String. So you have to remember the Finding of the first call of m.find() or you use the while loop without the if statement. With a boolean flag you could keep track whether you found something or not to decide whether you want to print "Nothing found" afterwards.

Something like:

```
      boolean foundSomething = false;
           
      while(m.find()) {
        foundSomething = true;
        System.out.println(m.group());
      }
      if(!foundSomething){        
        System.out.println("Nothing found");
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use while alone because it is a fulfillment of the condition if it doesn't find what you are looking for it moves to the next use for or `do-while`

Comment: Ok. How would you do it with a for loop? I'm been trying for sometime.